# Limitar um valor especifico a uma string

Tags: c++, string, char

preciso limitar eem um valor especifico que seria 511

```
char command[512];
```

Eu tentei com

```
char command[512]; 
scanf("%511s",command);
if (StrToInt(command))>511)
printf("FIX ATK");
```

e esse também

```
char command[512]; 
scanf("%511s", command);
if (strlen(command) > 511)
printf("FIX ATK");
```

e não obtive sucesso, alguém sabe resolver?

Comment: Você quer que o tamanho entrado seja inferior a 512? Se for isso, qual a dificuldade ou problema? Ou quer limitar que o número digitado seja menor que 512? Se for isso porque não pede como número? Isto funciona: https://ideone.com/XtZAT9.

Answer (score -1):

Bom. aqui tens de definir se queres que o **valor** seja inferior a 512

> if (StrToInt(command))>511)

ou se queres que o **comprimento da string** seja inferior a 512.

> if (strlen(command) > 511)

De qualquer modo, para converteres string para inteiro, em c++, devias usar std::stoi.

Penso que devias explicar melhor a tua duvida